# Use playwright in end application (electron)

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, playwright

Hello everyone I use Playwright in my project on Vue+Electron.
In Electron builder settings use `externals: ['playwright-chromium']` but end users can`t use Playwright module with error:

> Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or
> updated. Please run the following command to download new browsers:
> npx playwright install

How users can use Playwright module without install Node and Playwright? What I can use to package browsers with Electron-Builder?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re seeing an error message related to Playwright, it’s likely that the necessary browser binaries have not been downloaded. Here are the steps to resolve this:

Install Playwright in your project with `npm i playwright`.
Download the required browsers with `npx playwright install`.
Add a post-install script in your `package.json` that copies the browser binaries to a known location in your project.

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "node copy-playwright-browsers.js"
}
```

Create the copy script `copy-playwright-browsers.js` that copies the browser binaries from the `node_modules` directory to the desired directory in your project.

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');

const browsersDir = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'playwright', '.local-browsers');
const destinationDir = path.join(__dirname, 'playwright-browsers');

fs.copySync(browsersDir, destinationDir);

process.env.PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH = path.join(__dirname, 'playwright-browsers');
```

Package your app with Electron-Builder with `npm run electron-builder`.
These steps should help to include the browser binaries when you package your Electron app. If you continue to encounter issues, consider opening an issue in the Playwright GitHub repository. Remember to include details about your setup and the exact error message you’re seeing.